# Data context lost in special case with blaze rendering

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

i'm trying to update my application from meteor 0.7.x to 0.8
I solved a lot of thing to be blaze compliant but i still have some problem with some special case where data context is lost inside a call to a helper like this
    {{#if myHelper}}{{lostData}}{{/if}}

i did a sample to explain the problem and to allow everyone to reproduce it :

```
open a browser and the console
then go to http://bugdatacontext.meteor.com/
have a look a the console before and after should be the same, but it's not.
```

the source code is here : https://github.com/Rebolon/meteor-renderDataContext-bug

[original post]
i'm trying to update my application from meteor 0.7.x to 0.8
I solved a lot of thing to be blaze compliant but i still have some problem with html attributes that should be dynamic.

for example i have to render some url :

```
<img src="/path/to/image/{{_id}}" />
```

with Sparks it works well, but with blaze {{_id}} is just null when it's used inside html attributes, whereas it's ok when used inside html tags like this :

```
<span>{{_id}}</span>
```

What is the right way to generate my url dynamically ?
Thanks

After some more investigation it appears that the problem is not about attributes because if i use {{_id}} before the img tag, it displays the _id. I'm still looking for the problem; If the solution is interesting for everybody i will let the question, in other case i will remove it.
Thanks for comments

Comment: I have just tested this and Blaze allows to render <img src="/path/{{_id}}"> and <span>{{_id}}</span>.

Answer (score 0):

After creating an issue in meteor github project, i had this answer :

```
UI.toHTML(template.extend({"data": data}));

instead of

UI.renderWithData(template, data).render().toHTML();
```

source: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2044